# Model contains List<OtherModel> but content is not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my first Question on stackoverflow, I hope I am doing it right ;) The search doesn't provided any hint to my current problem. I am new to ASP.NET MVC 4.

I've set up a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Project using Razor-HTML-Engine. I created two Models:

**Model Client**

```
[Table("Clients")]
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<License> Licenses { get; set; }
}
```

**Model License**

```
[Table("Licenses")]
public class License
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ActivationHistory> ActivationHistory { get; set; }
}
```

I read that I will have to make a new Class deriving from DbContext in Order to get this working properly:

```
public class ClientDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }
}
```

---

In my opinion this gives me:

- two Tables with PrimaryKeys and the association between the Tables (1:N)
- the ability to create a Client Object and use `Client.Licenses.Add()` to add a new Element to the Table *after using db.SaveChanges()*
- a Client with all Licenses using `var t = db.Clients.Single(a => a.Id == 1);`
- Am I right so far?

I now added sample data to the Client:

```
// Get Context
var c = new ClientDbContext();

// Create new License
var n1 = new License();
// Testdata
n1.SerialNumber = "12345";

// Get test Client
var test = c.Clients.Single(v => v.ContactName.Contains("Testclient"));

// Add test License to Client
test.Licenses.Add(n1);

// Save Changes
c.SaveChanges()
```

Checking the Database, a new Row in the License-Table has been added. There is a foreign Key Client_Id pointing to the correct client *Testclient*

But if I try to show the information from License on the View, there are no Entries at all:

```
                 foreach (var item in Model.Licenses)
                 {
                     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNumber)
                 }
```

I am using the default Controller-Method:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);
        if (client == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(client);
    }
```

Can anyone please give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mark your navigation properties(Licenses) as `virtual`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the problem! So easy, I miss the forest for the trees ;)